# Installing iPhone App to iPhone

Tags: iphone

I followed the tutorial from this site:

http://theappleblog.com/2008/08/04/tutorial-build-a-simple-rss-reader-for-iphone/

to make my first iPhone application, now I would like to test this application on my iPhone, what steps do I need to take in order to do this?

Comment: Be forewarned: that tutorial, while a nice read, has horrible, horrible code full of memory leaks. Do *not* use that code in a production app. You'll definitely be sorry if you do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two choices. You can register to become an iPhone developer like most people do on the [iPhone Dev Center](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/), and then deploy directly to the device by selecting "Device - iPhone OS 2.2" in the Overview menu and then hitting Build and Go.

If you're not using any 2.2-specific APIs, you can compile with "Device - iPhone OS 2.1" and then send your app bundle over to a jailbroken iPhone via SFTP, and fake the codesign process using the ldid utility, allowing you to mess around with your apps on the device without registering to become a developer, and without having the headache of installing the open toolchain.

Answer (score 3):

Become a registered iPhone developer. You can't deploy to the phone without doing this first.

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/