# iPhone executable file

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, xcode

how can i create a executable file to iphone? i have written my code in objective c using xcode i want to create a application that must run on any iphone..

i want to go by a legal way with no jail breaking. 
please any body help..

Comment: i have created a new project, a view based project, built and run its running fine in simulator.. for that i want to create an executable file and should run in to my iphone how can i do this?

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/652129/installing-iphone-app-to-iphone and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1000721/is-it-possible-to-load-a-separate-application-into-the-iphone, among many others.

Comment: For what I understand you are at the last step of App developing process. Now it's time to pay Apple and put your app in the App store. There is NO legal way to distribute your iPhone app, trough another channel than the App store. http://developer.apple.com/programs/iphone/distribute.html

Answer (score 2):

You need to be a registered iPhone developer for this; sign up at [developer.apple.com](http://developer.apple.com). Once you've signed up, the way forwards should be pretty clear; but in short you need to create a provisioning profile for your device, test your application and submit it to the App Store. Once that is done, anyone can buy/download your application.

Comment: hi.. if i register by paying $99 .. we are going to get some certificates rite? k after registering how can we convert our project to executable file which can be run on iPhone? does that executable file can be run on any iPhone?

Comment: You compile it, just as you would do for the one for the simulator, and install it to test. This is all detailed in the documentation you get when you've registered.